# IPSec Netgear BS200 and Linksys LRT214 - Can't reach devices

Tags: ipsec, site-to-site-vpn

I have set up the first time an **IPSec site to site tunnel**.
The tunnel is **up and running** from a **Netgear BR200** and the **Linksys LRT214** Router.
Network 1 has 192.168.**100.x** and the Network 2 has 192.168.**1.x**!

Linksys displays "**connected**" and in the Netgear router I see the **green** connection icon.

Now I try to open the routers webinterface from Network 2 on the Server (192.168.100.4) on Network 1.
After entering 192.168.1.1 in the browser I get "connection timeout".

Also if I try to ping any other device in the Network 2 I get "Destination is not reachable".

Do I miss here something? Any local setting on the client/server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a **missing static route**.

I added the static route for the IP range 192.168.1.x to the external WAN IP address of the other router and now it is working.